# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzait()Ljava/util/ArrayList; in class Lcom/ Error?

Tags: android, firebase

Hi I'm learning to use Firebase from an Udacity Course.
I got this error when I ran my app and have no clue about it.
11-23 16:48:34.995 3947-3947/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat, PID: 3841
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzait()Ljava/util/ArrayList; 
in class Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions; 
or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions' appears in /data/data/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat/files/.jrebel/load-dexes/bundle12/libraries24.zip)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth$3.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth$3.zzp(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.addApi(Unknown Source) 
at com.firebase.ui.auth.util.CredentialsAPI.initGoogleApiClient(CredentialsAPI.java:147) 
at com.firebase.ui.auth.util.CredentialsAPI.<init>(CredentialsAPI.java:65)
at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.ChooseAccountActivity.onCreate(ChooseAccountActivity.java:102)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)                    at com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.android.agent.JRebelInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(SourceFile:93)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)    
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
11-23 16:48:35.176 3947-3975/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychatE/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
```

Can anyone help me?

UPDATE build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
// Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.0'

    // FirebaseUI Auth only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.0'

    // FirebaseUI Storage only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.0.0'

    // Single target that includes all FirebaseUI libraries above
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.0'

    // Firebase Auth
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: can you post your build.gradle of your app module?

Comment: I have posted it. Please have a look.

Comment: refer this https://github.com/udacity/and-nd-firebase

Comment: Does the logcat output include this warning: `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely do to a version incompatibility between Firebase, and FirebaseUI. I ran into the same issue, and spent 30-45 min trying to figure it out.  Ultimately what I did in order to keep going with the "Firebase in a Weekend" tutorial was:

`git checkout 1.04-firebase-auth-firebaseui-signin`

This will switch to the branch at this point in the tutorial. It works fine after doing so.

Maybe not the ideal answer as to what the problem is, but will get you going again with the course.

Answer (score 9):

Matching the versions resolves this.
In Compatibility with Firebase / Google Play Services Libraries, it matches

```
FirebaseUI Version   Firebase/Play Services Version

   1.0.0                   9.8.0
```

So if dependencies are changed to

> ```
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
> compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.0'
> ```

instead of

> ```
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
> compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.0'
> ```

which is the latest available firebase version for firebaseUI version, the app works fine

Comment: Confirming: I was running Firebase dependencies at `10.2.0`. Downgrading them to `10.0.1` (running `firebase-ui-auth` at `1.1.1`) resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add :
*compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:x.x.x'*(find the right version [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)). They missed to say that you also need to add play-services-auth dependency for google authentication to work.