# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzait()Ljava/util/ArrayList;

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

I am trying to integrate login using gmail.
Error is pointing to `addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)`.

```
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this) 

               .enableAutoManage(this, this)

               .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)

               .build();
```

Comment: anybody having solution for this

Comment: not sure, but i think it's related to using non compatible (too old) google services dependencies (jar files) it's good to post the whole stacktrace too

Comment: Most likely you have incompatible versions of FirebaseUI and the main Firebase library, or are depending on multiple versions of Firebase and Google Play Services. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40795872/209103. It could also be that your API level is too low. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38951385/209103

Comment: thank you all for replay .i cleared that issue by updating google service.